# How to find the surface area of the spout of a teapot?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to find the surface area of a teapot. I found the surface area of the body of the teapot by taking a picture of it, graphing the picture and then calculating the surface area of revolution. However, I don't know how to find the surface area (or an estimate of the surface area) of the teapot's spout. Here are some pictures of teapots with spouts that looks like the one that my teapot has:

[image: spout 1]

[image: spout 2]

[image: spout 3]

I would seriously appreciate it if someone can give me details about how to find the surface area of the spout, or provide links to articles or papers that shows how to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks to me like elliptic integrals are going to appear since the cross sections of the spout are elliptical. That means it would be very difficult to actually integrate.

Comment: You should look Dupin's cyclides and the way one can connect them : https://u-bourgogne.hal.science/hal-00785322/document

Comment: Any comment on my remark ?